# Bash command quoting issue

Tags: bash, quoting

I have this weird issue, I can't understand why is happening. It should be a piece of cake for any bash ninja.

```
OPTIONS="-auto -batch -ignore 'Path one' -ignore 'Path two' -ignore 'Path three'"
unison $OPTIONS a b
```

I expected this to be translated as...

```
unison -auto -batch -ignore 'Path one' -ignore 'Path two' -ignore 'Path three' a b
```

...and just work. But it doesn't. When running the full command, I have no problems, unison is ok with that. But when I run the command `unison $OPTIONS a b`, unison complains:

```
Usage: unison [options]
    or unison root1 root2 [options]
    or unison profilename [options]

For a list of options, type "unison -help".
For a tutorial on basic usage, type "unison -doc tutorial".
For other documentation, type "unison -doc topics".

unison was invoked incorrectly (too many roots)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BASH FAQ entry #50: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
options=(-auto -batch -ignore 'Path one' ...)
unison "${options[@]}" a b
```

Comment: It works now. I will take a look at this FAQ the next time before asking. Thank you!