# Honoring quotes while reading shell arguments from a file

Tags: arrays, bash

In bash, I can pass quoted arguments to a command like this:

```
$ printf '[%s]\n' 'hello world'
[hello world]
```

But I can't get it to work right if the argument is coming from a subshell:

```
$ cat junk
'hello world'
$ printf '[%s]\n' $(cat junk)
['hello]
[world']
```

Or:

```
$ cat junk
hello world
$ printf '[%s]\n' $(cat junk)
[hello]
[world]
```

Or:

```
$ cat junk
hello\ world
$ printf '[%s]\n' $(cat junk)
[hello\]
[world]
```

How do I do this correctly?

EDIT: The solution also needs to handle this case:

```
$ printf '[%s]\n' abc 'hello world'
[abc]
[hello world]
```

So this solution doesn't work:

```
$ cat junk
abc 'hello world'
$ printf '[%s]\n' "$(cat junk)"
[abc 'hello world']
```

---

The question at [Bash quoting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564250/bash-quoting-issue) has been suggested as a duplicate. However, it isn't clear how to apply its accepted answer; the following fails:

```
$ cat junk
abc 'hello world'
$ FOO=($(cat junk))
$ printf '[%s]\n' "${FOO[@]}"
[abc]
['hello]
[world']
```

Comment: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!" http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: If you want a general-purpose solution, `printf %q` is it. That is to say: `printf -v var_q %q "$var"` will put an eval-safe version of the contents of `"$var"` in `"$var_q"`.

Comment: @rici: That solution does work here. See the edit above.

Comment: Err. The answer to `abc 'hello world'` is "don't do that". Use a NUL-delimited stream to represent a shell array unambiguously and safely.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: I'm only using printf to illustrate the resulting arguments.

Comment: @Abscissa, my point is that you can use `printf` to **generate** correctly-escaped values. I'm not telling you to change how you illustrate anything. It's a multi-purpose tool.

Comment: That said -- when you do `printf '[%s]\n' $(cat junk)`, that **does not** `eval` anything at all, so your title and your question text don't match up.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: There's seriously no way to get bash to treat an eval result the same as interactive input?

Comment: @Abscissa, you aren't calling `eval` at all!

Comment: @abscissa: There's a difference between command substitution (which is what you are doing) and eval. If you want to eval, use `eval` (with lots of care), but you will still need an array to do what you want.

Comment: @Abscissa, ...also, you **shouldn't** use `eval`. It does what you ask for, but it's a major security risk.

Comment: @Abscissa, ...that said: `eval "printf '[%s]\n' $(<junk)"` will have your desired output. It'll also blow holes in your security if an untrusted user can ever write to `junk`.

Comment: ...instead, you should write your content as a NUL-delimited stream, and follow FAQ 1's rules for reading it.

Comment: I'd reopen this (I have the gold-badge dupehammer here, same as @rici does), but frankly, it's not a great question right now: When it says output is "going to an eval", the title is completely misleading, since you don't use `eval` at all.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that "command substitution" != "eval".

Comment: I'd suggest reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser, or at least glancing at the diagram at http://stuff.lhunath.com/parser.png

Comment: I agree with Charles, but you could use this: `declare "FOO=($(cat junk))"`. That's *equivalent to eval*, and you need to use the same amount of caution.

Comment: ...the notable thing you'll see in that diagram, or the larger textual parser explanation, is that expansion results don't go all the way up to the top layer of processing -- only the ones _below_ the expansion that takes place. `eval` goes all the way back to the top.

Comment: Okay. @rici -- since we're trying to load the array's contents from a file, I think that this is distinguishable from the question it's currently marked as a dupe of (as it's not obvious how to leverage the accepted answer correctly without getting back into the same problem). Would you object to re-opening?

Comment: BTW -- `FOO=($(cat junk))` is **not** what the other answer is telling you to do. Granted, knowing how to use it correctly when reading from a file isn't obvious, but attempting to leverage it that way is a misreading.

Comment: ...also, the claim that command substitution results behave differently from expanding other variables is flatly inaccurate. `foo=( $junkvar )` would have exactly the same problem.

Comment: FWIW, retrieving the input from a file was just for the sake of illustration, in my actual use-case it's really the output of a custom CLI tool. BTW, feel free to edit the OP as appropriate (I think that's possible here?), as it seems I was mixed up on some things.

Comment: (as another side note -- avoid all-uppercase variable names for shell-local variables; these are reserved for shell builtins and environment variables honored by the system. See the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, speaking to naming convention -- keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one good solution here, but you can choose between bad ones.

---

### This answer requires changing the file format:

Using a NUL-delimited stream for the file is the safest approach; literally any C string (thus, any string bash can store as an array element) can be written and read in this manner.

```
# write file as a NUL-delimited stream
printf '%s\0' abc 'hello world' >junk

# read file as an array
foo=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' entry; do
  foo+=( "$entry" )
done <junk
```

If valid arguments can't contain newlines, you may wish to leave out the `-d ''` on the reading side and change the `\0` on the writing side to `\n` to use newlines instead of NULs. Note that UNIX filenames can contain newlines, so if your possible arguments include filenames, this approach would be unwise.

---

### This answer *almost* implements shell-like parsing semantics:

```
foo=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' entry; do
  foo+=( "$entry" )
done < <(xargs printf '%s\0' <junk)
```

`xargs` has some corner cases surrounding multi-line strings where its parsing isn't *quite* identical to how a shell does. It's a 99% solution, however.

---

### This answer requires a Python interpreter:

The Python standard library `shlex` module supports POSIX-compliant string tokenization which is more true to the standard than that implemented by `xargs`. Note that bash/ksh extensions such as `$'foo'` are not honored.

```
shlex_split() {
  python -c '
import shlex, sys
for item in shlex.split(sys.stdin.read()):
    sys.stdout.write(item + "\0")
'
}
while IFS= read -r -d '' entry; do
  foo+=( "$entry" )
done < <(shlex_split <junk)
```

---

### These answers pose a security risk:

...specifically, if the contents of `junk` can be written to contain shell-sensitive code (like `$(rm -rf /)`), you don't want to use either of them:

```
# use declare
declare "foo=($(cat junk))"

# ...or use eval directly
eval "foo=( $(cat junk) )"
```

---

If you want to be sure that `foo` is written in a way that's safe to read in this way, and you control the code that writes to it, consider:

```
# write foo array to junk in an eval-safe way, if it contains at least one element
{ printf '%q ' "${foo[@]}" && printf '\n'; } >junk;
```

---

Alternately, you could use:

```
# write a command which, when evaluated, will recreate the variable foo
declare -p foo >junk
```

and:

```
# run all commands in the file junk
source junk
```

Comment: Cool. I'd use `declare -p foo` to write out the serialized value -- it also works with empty arrays. That's a good format for reading the data, too, if that's possible; you could  think of it as BSON :)

Comment: Thanks! FWIW, I just whipped up a little util to make it easier to actually send such a null-delim list to a program: https://github.com/Abscissa/safeArg

Comment: @Abscissa, incidentally, GNU xargs with the `-0` argument will do likewise, albeit with the additional behavior of splitting long argument lists off into multiple invocations